# Android Scheduled Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, schedule

I'm building an app and I need to schedule a notification that remember the user to access the app. I need this notification to be shown a month ahead of the last time the app was used

Comment: Add some code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 8):

`AlarmManager` has access to the system alarm services. With the help of AlarmManager you can schedule execution of code in future. AlarmManager object can’t instantiate directly however it can be retrieved by calling `Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)`. AlarmManager is always registered with `Intent`. When an alarm goes off, the Intent which has been registered with AlarmManager, is broadcasted by the system automatically. This intent starts the target application if it is not  running. It is recommended to use AlarmManager when you want your application code to be run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.

There is an [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example).