# Is it possible to schedule notifications in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, schedule

I am currently working on a program. The program should ask the use when he wants to be reminded of something during a specific day of the week (example, during Thursdays). Is this possible? Is it even possible to send notifications at a certain time of the day? 
Of course, the program may be closed by the user, but will notifications still appear even after the user closes the app?

How can I do these?
Please, I really do need help on this one.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548999/android-scheduled-notifications [possible duplicate]

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Simple case - schedule starting of android service which will notificate user.